# Set old records as inactive when updating table with new data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a table where I want to preserve old records. I want to distinguish between a current record and an old record by setting an 'active' flag to be 1 or 0.

Example:
Table #a has all the current data.

| id | value | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |

Table #b has new data

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |

Intention:

1. record 1 should not be modified in table #a (does not exist in #b)
2. record 2 should be updated as inactive, with new values inserted (#b provides new value)
3. record 3 should not be modified (no change to value)
4. record 4 should be inserted (does not exist in a)

Desired end result

| id | value | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |

This is my solution.  My question is, is there a better way??

```
SELECT *
INTO #a
FROM (
SELECT 1 id, 1 value, 1 active
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2,1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,3,1
)t

SELECT *
INTO #b
FROM (
SELECT 2 id, 7 value
UNION ALL SELECT 3,3
UNION ALL SELECT 4,4
)t

SELECT * FROM #a

SELECT *
INTO #ut
FROM (
    SELECT id, value FROM #b
    EXCEPT
    SELECT id, value FROM #a
) ut

UPDATE a
    SET active = 0
FROM #a a
INNER JOIN #ut ut ON a.id = ut.id

INSERT INTO #a
SELECT ut.id, ut.value, 1 FROM #ut ut

SELECT * FROM #a
```

Note: I am also timestamping the records as well, but I wanted to keep this example as simple as possible.  Unique key would be combination of id and createdon timestamp

Edit: I should add some of these tables I'm working with have millions of rows, so performance is important.

Comment: This is where a datetime column (date_last_updated) would come in handy. Add `DECLARE @run_date datetime = GETDATE();` to the top of the script. When you insert or update to your main table, make sure to update the `date_last_updated = @run_date` . Then, run a `DELETE FROM table WHERE date_last_updated < @run_date;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- set active to 0 when a new record will be added by a matched record
merge into #a a using #b b on a.id = b.id
  when matched and a.value != b.value then update set active = 0;
-- create new record for changed values and new items
merge into #a a using #b b on a.id = b.id and a.value = b.value
  when not matched then insert(id, value, active) values(b.id, b.value, 1);
```

Comment: Is there a minimum version of SQL server required for this logic?

Comment: This is supported by all SQL version

Comment: Note: This has been updated from the original answer to accommodate the flagging of inactive records and insert change records.

Comment: I tried using merge before but I was trying to use just one merge, didn't work.  I like this solution thank you.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the challenge, and how our solution tackles it.